# Flutter/Dart - A RenderFlex overflowed by 99804 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can anybody see why I'm getting this error on the first child: Column?  I'm using a stack in my build. and tried wrapping each widget in a Flexible widget but can't figure out where the code is overflowing. The screen flashes the telltale yellow/black renderflex lines for just a second but then seems to render just fine. The messages in the console are annoying though as is the little yellow/black flash at the beginning.

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99804 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///E:/FlutterProjects/myproject/lib/builders/CustomPageView.dart:47:26
```

Here's the code. Line 47 is the first `child: column`.

```
class _CustomPageViewState extends State<CustomPageView> {
  Widget build(context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.speakcrafts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return createViewItem(widget.speakcrafts[currentIndex], context);
      },
    );
  }

    Widget createViewItem(SpeakContent speakcraft, BuildContext context) {
          var contsize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.60;
        var contHeightsize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    
    return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.black12,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(
                  speakcraft.gavatar,
                  height: contsize,
                  width: contsize,
                ),
                PlayerWidget2(url: kUrl),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

And here's the full error code with chunhunghan's ConstrainedBox suggestion;

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99325 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Row file:///E:/FlutterProjects/speakoholic/lib/builders/CustomPageView.dart:121:25
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#d5393 relayoutBoundary=up8 OVERFLOWING
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 556.9); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=674.9, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(674.9, 100000.0)
  direction: horizontal
  mainAxisAlignment: center
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  textDirection: ltr
  verticalDirection: down
  child 1: RenderErrorBox#d3900
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 100385 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///E:/FlutterProjects/speakoholic/lib/builders/CustomPageView.dart:49:28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had to follow the error further down the widget tree of this widget;

```
child: PlayerWidget2(url: kUrl))
```

Within `PlayerWidget2` was a path that was null prior to a `PageViewBuilder` being built. This threw a null path error which lead to the renderflex error. Once built, the null was filled in with a path. So in order to get rid of the errors I simply added a default path to the widget to fill in the null until the PageViewBuilder was built.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your whole body content as a child of SingleChildScrollView [SinglechildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) widget which may help you to overcome from this issue,or you can also make use of listview which can arrange list of widgets properly [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

Comment: Wrapping the body in a SingleChildScrollView didn't work- left a thick white bar at bottom of screen. Unsure about listview as I'm already using pageview.in the State; IE                                                                                                                        class _CustomPageViewState extends State<CustomPageView> {
  Widget build(context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.speakcrafts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return createViewItem(widget.speakcrafts[currentIndex], context);
      },
    );
  }

Comment: can you post your UI screenshot here ? or else drop a mail[ hi2friends90@gmail.com ] to me we will discuss ,i will fix the problem for you